# windows phone 8 imagebrush getting path

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i have this code

```
 <Grid Width="160" x:Name="grd">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush x:Name="img"  ImageSource="Assets/Icons/tab-inactive.png" />
                        </Grid.Background>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtacticve" Text="Rating" Tap="TextBlock_Tap_1" />
                    </Grid>
```

while tapping the textblock the tap event will be called.how can i get the complete path of the imagesource in this tap event in code behind? i am really at the lost here how to get to the imagesource in my codebehind event.

Comment: i really doesn't what you are asking for ?

Comment: i want imagesource value "Assets/Icons/tab-inactive.png" when i click on the textblock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution could be the following one :

In your XAML code, you can bind your `TextBlock.Tag` property to the `Grid.Background` property you need. It could be useful to do it in XAML rather than code behind if your `Grid` is not the first parent (no need to find the required parent with recursive C# code) :

```
  <Grid Width="160" x:Name="grd">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush x:Name="img"  ImageSource="Assets/Icons/tab-inactive.png" />
        </Grid.Background>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtacticve" Text="Rating" Tap="TextBlock_Tap_1" Tag="{Binding ElementName=grd, Path=Background}" />
    </Grid>
```

Then in your code behind, you just have to cast and use the `TextBlock.Tag` property that way :

```
 private void TextBlock_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
 {
    var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    if (textBlock != null)
    {
        var test = ((BitmapImage)((ImageBrush)textBlock.Tag).ImageSource).UriSource.OriginalString;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
private void TextBlock_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (Grid)txtacticve.Parent;
    var img = grid.Background;
    var path = ((BitmapImage)(((ImageBrush)(img)).ImageSource)).UriSource.AbsolutePath;
}
```